# Convert public key .cer file into raw text

Tags: authentication, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have sent a CSR to a cert authority and they have sent me an encrypted public cert with extension .cer and it is encrypted.

Can this file be converted into raw text format similar to this:
https://github.com/ndi-trusted-data/myinfo-demo-app/blob/master/ssl/staging_myinfo_public_cert.cer

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not encrypted, and 'raw text' is a contradiction in terms. It may be in PKCS#12 format, or it may already be text. If the former, you can convert it with the `openssl` utility. Off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The **Text-Form** is PEM ([RFC1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421)). You can convert it like the following:

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` + linebreak + Base64({bytes-of-certificates}) +  linebreak + `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` + linebreak

**Edited**

- As [@user207421](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/user207421) pointed out - the binary form is **not encrypted**, it is [DER](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-199407-S/en) **encoded**.
- Added line breaks as [@dave_thompson_085](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2868801/dave-thompson-085) pointed out to [RFC7468](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468.html#section-2) section 2.

Comment: That should be Base64_with_linebreaks_every_64char(DER), and have linebreaks between it and the BEGIN and END lines and after the END line. See also RFC 7468 section 2, which clarifies and reiterates 1421.